# How to commit and push file from different directory to the same repository in github

Tags: git, github

So I already have this repository which has bunch of files I have committed and pushed. Now I'm trying to push some files but from different directory in my PC to the same repository. What can I do?

Comment: You do not push *files* to a Git repository. You push *commits*. If you want to push some new commits, you must make those new commits, then push them. That's all there is to it, really.

Answer (score 0):

if your project is in 2 different directories of same computer, it will work as the project is in 2 different PCs.

just imagine your codes are at different computer, so you have to push & pull the project edits separately.

e.g. if you push something in project from one directory, then pull that code from another directory to make both project same, so that no error occur when u push more changes from 2nd directory codes

Comment: Thanks!,I finally understand that I have to pull the code first before pushing